Spinner with action and output with bubbletea library
I'm willing to have a spinner displayed while running a function that have output to print.
I cannot figure out how to do so and have pretty print, anyone already faced that ? I cannot find any example either
FYI: I'm using https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea library to display the spinner.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles/spinner"
    tea "github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea"
    "github.com/charmbracelet/lipgloss"
)

var (
    textStyle    = lipgloss.NewStyle().Foreground(lipgloss.Color("252")).Render
    spinnerStyle = lipgloss.NewStyle().Foreground(lipgloss.Color("69"))
    helpStyle    = lipgloss.NewStyle().Foreground(lipgloss.Color("241")).Render
)

func main() {
    m := spinnerModel{}
    m.resetSpinner()

    var p = tea.NewProgram(m)
    go func() {
        checkServer()
        p.Quit()
    }()

    if _, err := p.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("could not run program:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

type spinnerModel struct {
    index   int
    spinner spinner.Model
}

func (m spinnerModel) Init() tea.Cmd {
    return m.spinner.Tick
}

func (m spinnerModel) Update(msg tea.Msg) (tea.Model, tea.Cmd) {
    switch msg := msg.(type) {
    case tea.KeyMsg:
        switch msg.String() {
        case "ctrl+c", "q", "esc":
            return m, tea.Quit
        default:
            return m, nil
        }
    case statusMsg:
        return m, tea.Quit
    case spinner.TickMsg:
        var cmd tea.Cmd
        m.spinner, cmd = m.spinner.Update(msg)
        return m, cmd
    default:
        return m, nil
    }
}

func (m *spinnerModel) resetSpinner() {
    m.spinner = spinner.New()
    m.spinner.Style = spinnerStyle
    m.spinner.Spinner = spinner.Points
}

func (m spinnerModel) View() (s string) {
    var gap string
    switch m.index {
    case 1:
        gap = ""
    default:
        gap = " "
    }

    s += fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s\n\n", m.spinner.View(), gap, textStyle("Spinning..."))
    //qs += helpStyle("h/l, ←/→: change spinner • q: exit\n")
    return
}

const url = "https://charm.sh/"

type statusMsg int

type errMsg struct{ error }

func (e errMsg) Error() string { return e.error.Error() }

func checkServer() tea.Msg {
    println("Checking...")

    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        println("Checked")
    }

    return statusMsg(200)
}

The spinner is overwritting my checkServer function output while it is running.
Any way to do such thing ?

can you please show the code where: 1. you define and use a spinner, 2. you create the output for your application (e.g: an outline of your .View() function) ?

I've updated the question with the complete file. checkserver is a fake func for now, but the idea is here

check the code for the spinner widget, and its view is rendered, there probably are characters here that interact with how your own string is printed. To debug the printed string, use %q : fmt.Sprintf("%q%s\n\n", m.spinner.View(), gap, textStyle("Spinning...")). Check if the correct fix for your display is to add enough spaces, or issue ncurse specific sequences.
